# MIDO: ValueError: variable int must be a positive integer

Tags: mido

In my code I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Midi Projects/symbolToChord_v1.py", line 160, in <module>
    mo.save("songWithChords.mid") 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mido/midifiles/midifiles.py", line 432, in save
    self._save(file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mido/midifiles/midifiles.py", line 445, in _save
    write_track(outfile, track)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mido/midifiles/midifiles.py", line 251, in write_track
    data.extend(encode_variable_int(msg.time))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mido/midifiles/meta.py", line 112, in encode_variable_int
    raise ValueError('variable int must be a positive integer')
ValueError: variable int must be a positive intege
```

I suppose I am running the latest version on MIDO.

```
pip freeze | grep mido
mido==1.2.9
```

what am doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but I had a similar problem.

The time attribute in mido is a bit confusing as it can either represents ticks or time deltas. From the documentation (https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/midi_files.html#about-the-time-attribute
):

> The time attribute is used in several different ways:

> inside a track, it is delta time in ticks. This must be an integer.
> in messages yielded from play(), it is delta time in seconds (time elapsed since the last yielded message)
> (only important to implementers) inside certain methods it is used for absolute time in ticks or seconds

You can also see this github issue for reference https://github.com/mido/mido/issues/189